# CocoaPods "editable" mode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, git-submodules, cocoapods

Python's Pip has an `-e` flag that can be used to install the package as a full git repo so it can be worked on and changes pushed back to origin master. What's the equivalent command for CocoaPods?

Is there a way to install a pod as a full git repo/submodule so commits can be made?

Comment: I don't believe this currently exists. This sounds like a useful feature. You can submit a feature request on the [Github repo](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Use `--no-clean` when using `pod install` and `pod update`. This will keep the `.git` folder in `Pods/[YOUR_POD]` to allow you to commit/push directly from it.

Note: This currently does not work for SVN-backed pods as of 0.28 as cocoadpods uses the `svn export` command.